# html String returned by AJAX has a height of 0

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, web-applications

I am parsing a html string returned by an ajax call with jquery so I can position them the way I want but the `outerHeight()` function call on the string seems to be returning a value of 0.
Anybody experienced this before or got an idea why this could be so? The code fragment is given below.

```
(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/more",
      async:false,
      success: function(data){
        html = $(data);
        html.each(function(i){ 
          //position($(this));
          console.log($(this).html());
          console.log($(this).outerHeight());
        });
    $('#container').append(html);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML elements don't have a height until they are rendered, because the height will depend on the CSS that applies to the context they are rendered in.

If you add the HTML to the page and then access the height, you should get the correct number.